# Extension is not found in my .cs class

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  namespace MyExtensions
 {
public static class MyExtensions
{

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]
    public static bool LogError<T>(this T exp, string errorType = "",string extramessage = "") where T : System.Exception
    {
        if (!exp.Message.ToString().ToLower().Contains("thread was being aborted"))
        {
            string strDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM");
            string FilePath = (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Errors"]) + "LogError-" + strDate + ".txt");
            FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath, true);
            sWriter.WriteLine(("#------------" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "------------#"));
            sWriter.WriteLine(("Source: " + exp.Source));
            sWriter.WriteLine(("Method: " + exp.TargetSite.Name));
            sWriter.WriteLine(("Message: " + exp.Message));
            if (exp.InnerException != null)
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine(("Inner Exception: " + exp.InnerException.Message));
            }
            sWriter.WriteLine(("StackTrace: " + exp.StackTrace));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extramessage))
            {
                sWriter.WriteLine(" -- Extra Message: --  ");
                sWriter.WriteLine(extramessage);

            }
            sWriter.WriteLine("#------------------------------------------------#");
            sWriter.WriteLine();
            sWriter.WriteLine();
            sWriter.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

I have this class which contains an extension Method called `LogError` 
I created an asp form where it's server side code look like this :

```
   using MyExtensions
   public partial class Form : BasePage
   {
      public void GetEmpleye()
      {
        try{}
        catch(Exception ex)
        { ex.LogError();  }

      }
   }
```

`ex.LogError();` this line is giving me an error saying :

> System.Extension does not contain a definition of `LogError`

Comment: Your `MyExtensions` class is broken to start with - it's a static class, but you've put in a constructor. That's not allowed, so you should be getting an error there. Next, your `LogError` method is an instance method, and finally it doesn't have `this` as a modifier for the first parameter.

Comment: Extension methods must be static and the first parameter should be `this T exp`.

Comment: please check my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is not an extension method. It has to be `static` and it needs `this` in front of first parameter:

```
public static bool LogError<T>(this T exp, string errorType = "", string extramessage = "") where T : System.Exception
```

`ExtensionAttribute` is used in VB.NET. I'm not sure if you can use it to create an extension method in C#. But even if you can you need make your method `static`.

Comment: The method also needs to be static - and the static class shouldn't have an instance constructor...

Comment: @JonSkeet Was editing my answer while you posted that comment. Fixed now.

Comment: To answer your uncertainty - yes, you can use `[Extension]` to declare an extension method, although it's not idiomatic. It still needs to be a static method though.

Comment: can you please check my edit it is still giving me an error

Answer (score 1):

Extension method should be static and extension methods should to be declared in a nongeneric, non-nested, static class. Your listing:

```
public static bool LogError<T>(this T exp, string errorType = "", string extramessage = "") where T : System.Exception
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try call like this;

```
try{}
        catch(Exception ex)
        { ex.LogError<Exception>();  }
```

Since your method is like `LogError<T>` you may meed to define the `T` here.

EDIT: In my code I didn't use the `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]`.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384079.aspx

Comment: it did not work sing ex is not recognizing my function

Comment: I tried you code in my test solution. it works as above.

Comment: Comment `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]` and try. It says "Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'. Use the 'this' keyword instead."